# How to use django {% block %} to open clicked link in same page

Tags: python, django

This is my project.html page-[image]

Here the list in sidebar is coming  from database which contain project branch eg. IT and project subbranch eg. website Designing and Application Designing .What i want is that, when i click on the desired subbranch then all the projects having that subbranch display on right side of sidebar (where proj1 and proj2 are present). So please anybody tell me what is the optimum solution to do that.Currently i am thinking of some solutions-

1. To use {% block %} and extends concept.
2. To make separate .html file and pass some arguments from view.py so that content can change accordingly.

Actually i really don't know what is the correct way to do this, also don't know how to implement this.Can anybody please help me out.

**My modal.py file is-**

```
class branch(models.Model):
    branch_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class subbranch(models.Model):
    parentbranch = models.ForeignKey(branch)
    subbranch_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class project(models.Model):
    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    project_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="Images/Project")
    project_desc = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    project_duration = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    project_branch = models.ForeignKey(branch)
    project_subbranch = models.ForeignKey(subbranch)

    def __unicode__(self):              
            return str(self.project_title)
```

**My project.html file is-**

```
{% load staticfiles %}<!-- project.objects.filter(project_branch=3)
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Projects</title>
    <div>{% include "mutech/header.html" %}</div>
    <link href="{% static 'mutech/css/project_dropdown_menu2.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'mutech/css/project_dropdown_menu1.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
  .sidebar ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    border-right: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    width: 
}
         .slidebar_a, .slidebar_a:hover, .slidebar_a:focus, .slidebar_a:active, .slidebar_a:active 
            {
            background-color: white ;
            color:#337AB7;
            }
         #project_dropdown_col
            {
            background-color:white;
            }    
        .midDiv_project
            {
            min-height:580px;
            padding-top:  8.2%;
            }
    </style>
</head> 
<body>

    <div id="wrapper" class="midDiv_project">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
            <div class="row" style="background-color:#AEAEAE;">
              <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:hsl(0, 0%, 97%);min-height:580px;margin-lef:-100px;width:21%;border-right: 1px solid #e7e7e7;">
                  <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation" >
            <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/mutech/aboutus/" class="slidebar_a"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                                      <!-- Sidebar -->

{% if branch_list %}
    {% for q in branch_list %}

            <li>
                <a href="#" class="slidebar_a"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i> {{ q.branch_title }}    
                    {# hello #}
{% for p in subbranch_list %}
        {% if q.id == p.parentbranch_id  %}
                     <span class="fa arrow"></span></a> 

            {{ break }}
        {% endif %}             
{% endfor %} 
                    {% for p1 in subbranch_list %}
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        {% if q.id == p1.parentbranch_id  %}
                                <li><a href="#" class="slidebar_a">{{ p1.subbranch_title }}</a></li>
                        {% endif %} 
                    </ul>
                    {% endfor %}                

            </li>
    {% endfor %}  
{% endif %}     
                </ul>
            </div>
                <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->

              </div>
                <div class="col-md-9" >
                    <div>

                        <div class="container" >
                        <div class="row">
                            <h2>Projects List</h2>

            {% if project_list %}
              {% for q in project_list %}
                <div class="col-md-3" style="border:1px solid blak;height:250px;margin:2%">
                    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#{{ q.project_title }}">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-hover" src="../../../media/{{q.project_image}}" alt="Error" style="height:70%; width:100%" /></a><br>
                    <center><p>{{ q.project_title }}</p></center><br>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
            <p>No Project Found</p>
          {% endif %}               


    </div>
 </div>



                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

         <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="{% static 'mutech/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="{% static 'mutech/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="{% static 'mutech/js/metisMenu.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="{% static 'mutech/js/sb-admin-2.js' %}"></script>






<div>{% include "mutech/footer.html" %}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**My view.py file is-**

```
def project_info(request):
    project_list = project.objects.all()
    branch_list = branch.objects.all()
    subbranch_list = subbranch.objects.all()
    context = {'branch_list':branch_list , 'subbranch_list':subbranch_list ,'project_list':project_list }
    return render(request, 'mutech/project.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more a general webdev architecture question than Django-specific, but here is my take:

- `{% block %}` is used to structure your template hierarchy, it  has little to do with your problem here. Your problem needs to be implement using templates, but also views (and maybe models).
- Your second solution proposal is better. But you can generalize further: since the page you want to create is extremely similar to the existing one (one displays only a subset of projects, the other all the projects), it probably make more sense to use the same template and view for both. All you need for that is that your existing view (that currently returns everything) accept optional parameters to filter by category and query the Model appropriately. Without parameter, you'll have everything, with a category_id parameter, you'll only see the projects from one category. That with as few duplicated code as possible, which is always desirable.
- It is also common to implement such filtering using an AJAX view, for a better user experience. But you should probably take this way later, once you feel more at ease with the Django, web application architecture and the MTV/MVC pattern.

Comment: Thanks @niconoe for answering. Please also tell me how to implement all the logic in django. Actually i am not having any idea that how can i filter projects just on clicking a link and display them.

Comment: Also if anybody is having any better approach to implement this rather than using template and AJAX, then please tell me.